# django-cms menu url doesn't work

Tags: javascript, django, menu, django-cms

I've installed django-cms.I made a collapsible menu.There are some categories and subcategories(childs etc)..No problem here.

But when I click on one of main categories,although its URL seems correct,it doesn't go to URL.Categories which don't have child/subcategories opens correctly and go URLs.But If a category have subcategories,when I click on category name,just it goes down and child/subcategories titles seem.

I think it may about Javascript code(can be about onclick).
But it may be some setting of django-cms and I want to ask because of it.

Is there anyone who have same problem?If anyone can help,I would be really happy.

Some details to make it more clear:

Now I have a left menu which seem like:

- Home
- Pets
  - Dogs
    - Terries
  - Cats
- Accessories
  - Collars
  - Roundels
- Contact

Now I have this.When I click contact,I go to contact's URL/page.No problem here.
But When I click "Pets",only Cats,dogs and other subcategories goes down and I can't go pets page/url but I also have a Pets page which its URL seems correct when mouse on it.

I want to do exactly:When I click pets,I want to go Pets page/URL and because of it has some subcategories on page that I go I want to see subcategories of it.I mean When I click and go to Pets page(I can't now) I also want to see subcategories(dogs,cats,) goes down on menu bar on Pets page like above.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not allowed to comment, so I write an answer...

This is likely a js issue. Django-cms also links to top-level pages if there are children. (Until you add redirects).

Did you try to right-click e.g. the "Pets" link and choose "open link in new tab/window" ?

If this does not help - what does your js look like?